# links inside modal appearing before opening the modal and messing up the page interface

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a modal which appears when a button is clicked but the links present inside the modal appears before even opening the modal, they are invisible though but they are present because if a user clicks on the page the link inside the modal gets clicked.

To see it, open [filemile.ga](http://filemile.ga) and hover your mouse over the logo.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">more</button>

 <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog"  >
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h2 class="modal-title">Top Searches</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

  lots of links here
     <p>Link1</p>
     <p>Link2</p>
     <p>Link3</p>       

</div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle and reproduce this? I can see the links just fine with this code.

Comment: open   http://filemile.ga and hover your mouse over the logo @pmahomme

Comment: Is it 'logo' or is it 'more' button?

Comment: the more button opens the modal dialog but you can already see the links on logo of the page, they are invisible but when you click at it, it opens the link @v.coder

Comment: somehow i do not see any links near the logo.. can you please paste a screenshot of it with links ..

Comment: also i observed that <style> is included inside the <script> tag on line 34 can you please correct it

Comment: thanks for pointing out @v.coder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog"  >` with `<div class="modal fade hide" id="myModal" role="dialog"  >`
This hide class will set your modal inaccessible, bootstrap will take it off when you click the button.

This site you commented uses Bootstrap 2.3 [link to documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/index.html). If you edit it, this site will help you.

Comment: it's working, but modal does'nt show up when the button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

I just and a CSS style that seems to resolve.

On the first div of the Modal, whose the id is **myModal** just add the flolowing:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" style="display:none;">
```